# Integrating Bounded Contexts using Database Views

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, integration, cqrs, bounded-contexts

is there anything wrong with using database views for data integration from multiple bounded contexts? in my mind it's the same thing as making a RPC call as the database view is encapsulating the structure/details for the data.

so from my read side i could have database views from multiple bounded contexts
collaborating to fulfill the UI screen requirements. are they tightly coupled, yes, but at least from my understanding this is very similar to what Udi Dahan calls the IT/Ops service.

thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bounded Contexts are part of the Domain, db is part of Persistence ergo you can use whatever you want for your UI reads as long as you don't change the Domain (it shouldn't happen, if the Domain is properly decoupled from Persistence).

Let me be more clear: you get the data from the db, the Domain isn't aware of it. From a design point of view, how you get the data is just a persistence detail. And it's ok (i'd say, even encouraged) to have the UI talking directly (or using a mediator) to Persistence for querying/reporting purposes.